# How to call two APIs inside redux action where one API call depends upon what was returned from the other?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need to call a second API inside my redux action, and that api needs to use a variable that is returned from my first API.

I've tried using .then() but wasn't able to get the data that was returned from the first one.

```js
export const getLoginCredential = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3500/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "EID": "123", "appName":"myapp" })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      payload: data
    })

    let roleId;
    data.userRoleLinkDTO.map(role => {
      if (role.isDefault === "Y") {
        roleId = role.roleID;
      }
    })
    return roleId;
  })
  .then(id => {
    console.log(id);
    fetch("http://localhost:3500/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/json"
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({"data" : [{ "name": "getThings", "urlparameter": { "appId": "1", "userId": "1234", "roleID": id }, "parameter": "" }]})
    })
  })
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(data => dispatch({
    type: FETCH_ROLE_MENU,
    payload: data
  }))
  .catch(err => console.log(err))
}
```

In my second API call, I want to use the roleId which I want to return from 
`.then(data => {
    dispatch({
      type: LOGIN_USER,
      payload: data
    })
   })`

Answer (score 1):

As you have discovered, a dispatched action does not reliably return what you're expecting. While this may not necessarily be the case, I never use a return value from an action. What you can do instead is create a new action that accepts the `roleId` from your first call. You can technically do it in one function, but I think this makes logically sense.

Something along the lines of this should do what you need.

```
const fetchUserRole = ({roleId}) => dispatch => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3500/", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "data": [{ "name": "getList", "urlparameter": { "appId": "1", "someId": "555", "roleID": roleId }, "parameter": "" }] })

  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => dispatch({
      type: FETCH_ROLE_MENU,
      payload: data
    }))
}

export const getLoginCredential = () => dispatch => {
  fetch("http://localhost:3500/login", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "content-type": "application/json"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({ "EID": "444", "appName": "my-project.com" })

  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_USER,
        payload: data
      })
      const roleId = getLastMatchingRoleId(data) // line added from your clarification
      dispatch(fetchUserRole({ roleId }))
    })
}
```

Just an fyi, you didn't include where `roleId` is coming from. I'm assuming you're handling it somewhere you didn't show in your sample.

UPDATE:
Your implementation looks like you're just trying to find the last instance of an entry in the array that matches `role.isDefault === "Y"` in order to get the `roleId`. This is only an algorithm challenge and is not related to redux.

`Array#map` is used to create a new instance of the array. `Array#forEach` is the enumerable that is designed exactly for your use case.

My recommendation is to create a helper function that finds the approriate `roleId` for you. This isn't anything new. I just took your existing logic, changed it to use `beforeEach` (the appropriate enumerable) and turned into a function.

```
function getLastMatchingRoleId(data) {
  let roleId;
  data.userRoleLinkDTO.beforeEach(role => {
    if (role.isDefault === "Y") {
      roleId = role.roleID;
    }
  })
  return roleId;
}
```

All you need to do is incorporate this into my existing answer (which I have updated above)

Comment: If this does not answer your question, can you elaborate more on your issue regarding `// Here I want to map through my data and return the roleId so that I can use it in the second API call`?

Comment: thank you! Could you check out my updated post please? I added more to my problem...

Comment: @AnnahI Updated